# Home-made Arduino not receiving data

Tags: uploading, ftdi

Me and my friend recently built a Breadboard Arduino. It switches on fine, and the LED changes a bit. I have added a 5V FTDI cable, but it wouldn't upload, trying to fix this, I used my friends 5V FTDI Basic USB-To-Serial converter chip, thinking this would upload fine, as it was new, but it still wouldn't upload, giving the very long error:

```
Arduino: 1.5.8 (Windows XP), Board: "Arduino Duemilanove or Diecimila, ATmega328"

Build options changed, rebuilding all



C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\sketch_jan31a.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\sketch_jan31a.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\hooks.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\hooks.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WInterrupts.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WInterrupts.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_analog.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_analog.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_digital.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_digital.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_pulse.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_shift.c -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_shift.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\abi.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\abi.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\CDC.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\CDC.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial0.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial1.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial2.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HardwareSerial3.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\HID.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HID.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\IPAddress.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\IPAddress.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\main.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\main.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\new.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\new.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Print.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Print.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Stream.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Stream.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\Tone.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Tone.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\USBCore.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\USBCore.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WMath.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WMath.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=158 -DARDUINO_AVR_DUEMILANOVE -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WString.cpp -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WString.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\hooks.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WInterrupts.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_analog.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_digital.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_pulse.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\wiring_shift.c.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\abi.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\CDC.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\HID.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\IPAddress.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\main.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\new.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Print.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Stream.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\Tone.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\USBCore.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WMath.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\WString.cpp.o 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.elf C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp\sketch_jan31a.cpp.o C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/core.a -LC:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp -lm 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.elf C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.eep 

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.elf C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.hex 



Sketch uses 450 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30,720 bytes.

Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.

C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM8 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\DOCUME~1\George\LOCALS~1\Temp\build7021919583125132986.tmp/sketch_jan31a.cpp.hex:i 


avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr  3 2014 at 23:12:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM8
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x01

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

The light on the USB-To-Serial board lights once for each failed upload, but the sketch won't upload. I am trying to upload the blink sketch. The chip I am using is an Atmel AtMega328P-PU. All answers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you [burn the bootloader](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) onto your AtMega328?

Comment: No, I bought an AtMega328P with the bootloader preloaded.

Comment: Is this correct   Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600 (may be). AVRdude correct?

Comment: How did you connect the DTR pin? It might be that you have to manually reset the arduino before uploading.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Checked the output (I have verbose enabled). Overriding baud rate is 57600.

Comment: @Gerben - The DTR Pin is connected to reset button on breadboard.

Comment: DTR should be connected via a small capacitor, not directly.

Comment: @Gerben - Connected DTR with small capacitor. The capacitor is 0.10uf, and links over the IC notch in the breadboard, but I still can't upload. I've also tried a different FTDI cable, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Does the led stop changing when uploading? Does manually resetting the AVR work?

Comment: Is your bootloader configured for an external crystal?  If so, are you providing one of the appropriate frequency with loading capacitors?  What baud rate does your bootloader expect?

Comment: Hold the reset button (or just keep it from booting) and then a tiny bit before the arduino IDE tells "Uploading..." release the button. Then the bootloader should be able to get the serial data and flash the new software. (If the Arduino is not in bootloader (1-2sec after releasing the reset button) you can't program it)

Answer (score 1):

I would upload a blink sketch using the method Stephan suggested then plug it back into your breadboard.  If it runs the blink sketch then the problem is in your programming method, but  it is more likely there is something wrong in the setup.  Problems could be using the wrong crystal for your setup, mis-wired or loose connection, or having your chip turned around (happens more often than you think).  If it does run I would make sure that you are using all USB-to-Serial converter with all the wires used and having a resister on the reset pin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using an empty Uno-Board as a 'bridge' between the PC and the Bareduino (empty means with no controller chip). Just connect this guy via USB to the PC and then connect RX/TX, Ground, and Reset to your Bareduino. Just works fine for me.

Comment: How would this be superior to what the poster is doing (which has worked for many, including myself)?

Comment: Well - didn't he post because it is not working? It didn't work for me either and i am using my proposed solution since quite some time. Another advantage is - it is minimal invasive for the breaduino as only 3 cables have to be connected.

Comment: Four.  The same four you need with anything else.  Five if you get power from USB.

Answer (score 0):

The likely causes of failure are

- Wrong baud rate: you're already using 57600, the most common one.
- Rx and Tx cross connected: try connecting them the other way round.
- Wrong clock clock frequency in the chip: The tools usually assume an AtMega328 runs at 16MHz.
- Chip is not in bootloader/programming state, in the very first seconds after releasing the reset button or powering the arduino, the bootloader is listening for instructions to start reprogramming the chip via serial communication, if there is none it will continue running the program on it. Hold reset -> Hold upload -> Release upload -> Release reset.

The above assumes, of course, that you have a working board. If that isn't certain, follow @Nathan's advice to plug in a chip pre-programmed with a Blinky sketch to confirm it. I use a combined Blinky and HelloWorld sketch to prove both the basic functioning and the serial I/O in one test.

A couple of these are handy to keep around, too, for proving there is power or a logic HIGH where you expect it:

[image: LED with resistor]

```
       LED with current-limiting resistor on the cathode
```